# find all minimum elements of 2 dimensional array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, minimum

Having 2-dimensional array,`A`, I want to find minimum number in the array. However I can have more than one of that number. How can I find the [row col] of all minimum value?
Example:

```
2 3 4 2
1 6 7 1
9 8 3 1
```

It should return
[2,1]
[2,4]
[3,4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) will do the trick:

```
[I,J] = find(A == min(A(:)) );

disp([I J])
   2   1
   2   4
   3   4
```

Answer (score 2):

I belive this should work

```
[row,col]=find(a==min(a(:)))
```

where a is your matrix. Find can also output a linear index if you give just one output.